# Satellite fails to connect to host after hostname change

Tags: redhat, connectivity, foreman

I am running a RedHat Satellite 6.12 Server. I have a VM that I am hosting in VMware. After provisioning, I used `hostnamectl set-hostname` to change the hostname of the machine and in Satellite changed the `name` to the updated hostname. Satellite can no longer establish a connection to the host. Error is: `Error initializing command: RuntimeError - Failed to establish connection to remote host, exit code: 255`. More than likely this is something to do with foreman.

I have updated `/etc/hosts`, I can ping and dns resolve the VM from the CLI of the Satellite Server. What services or refresh do I need to restart in order to pick up this change in the UI?

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer on the RedHat website shortly after this. My `foreman-proxy` public key was somehow corrupted on the end host. I had to execute an `ssh-copy-id` for the foreman-proxy according to:

`[root@sat]# ssh-copy-id -i ~foreman-proxy/.ssh/id_rsa_foreman_proxy.pub root@host.example.com`
Answer comes from: https://access.redhat.com/solutions/7012983

Answer (score 0):

On the satellite WebUI try this,

Administer -> Settings -> Remote Execution -> Connect by IP -> set to "yes"